# in Android retrofit post method it shows 200 ok but the data doesn't went to server,

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm New to android, this is my retrofit post service .it show's 200ok and went to onResponse method, but Data does't  wen't to Server...?
please any one help me , thanks in advance.

This is my post method...

```
public interface Post {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("app_register.php")
    Call<Result> createUser(
            @Field("status ") String status,
            @Field("name") Boolean name,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("phone") String phone,
            @Field("city") String city,
            @Field("altphone") String altphone,
            @Field("address") String address,
            @Field("password") String password);
}
```

*MainActivity*

```
private void userSignUp( ){   
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage(" regester...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


        final boolean status =true;
        String name=et1.getText().toString().trim();
        String email=et2.getText().toString().trim();
        String phone=et3.getText().toString().trim();
        String city=et4.getText().toString().trim();
        String altphone=et5.getText().toString().trim();
        String address=et6.getText().toString().trim();
        String password=tie7.getText().toString().trim();


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


        //Defining retrofit api service
        Post service = retrofit.create(Post.class);

        Log.d(TAG, "onResult: Exception: " +service );

        //Defining the user object as we need to pass it with the call
        Registrationstatus user = new Registrationstatus(name,status, email, 
                                      password,phone,city,altphone,address);

        Log.d(TAG, "onResult1234: Exception: " +user);

        //defining the call
        Call<Result> call = service.createUser(
                user.getName(),
                user.getStatus(),
                user.getEmail(),
                user.getPhone(),
                user.getCity(),
                user.getAltphone(),
                user.getAddress(),
                user.getPassword()

        );


        call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, retrofit2.Response<Result> 
                                            response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                int statescode = response.code();

                System.out.println("retrofit response "+response);
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: NullPointerException: " +response );

                Toast.makeText(Regestration.this, " "+status, 
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure" +t );

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), 
                                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });
    }
```

*Result Class*

```
public class Result {

    @SerializedName("RegistrationStatus")
    @Expose
    private List<Registrationstatus> registrationStatus = null;

    public List<Registrationstatus> getRegistrationStatus() {
        return registrationStatus;
    }

    public void setRegistrationStatus(List<Registrationstatus> registrationStatus) {
        this.registrationStatus = registrationStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, "onResult: NullPointerException: " +response );` ??????

Comment: If you are getting into **onResponse** with status code: 200, then nothing wrong from the android side. You should check with API code and there may be chances to problem to insert to database from server.

Comment: Thank you for your response Venu.